# JSON encoding headers using Sendgrid

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, email, sendgrid

I am trying to change the filter status for the 'subscriptiontrack' using sendgrid. I think I am sending the headers incorrectly, but not totally sure. Working inside a symfony 1.4 framework.

**First I create an object of the header settings**

```
$hdr = new SmtpApiHeader();
$hdr->addFilterSetting('subscriptiontrack', 'enable', 0);
$hdr->as_string();
```

which sets the filter settings and encodes the string

**Then I send it off the email class**

```
sendTestEmail::sendEmail($contents, $mailFrom, $testGroup, $subject, $hdr);
```

**SvaSmtpApiHeader.class.php**

```
class SmtpApiHeader
{
function addFilterSetting($filter, $setting, $value)
    {
        if (!isset($this->data['filters'])) {
            $this->data['filters'] = array();
        }

        if (!isset($this->data['filters'][$filter])) {
            $this->data['filters'][$filter] = array();
        }

        if (!isset($this->data['filters'][$filter]['settings'])) {
            $this->data['filters'][$filter]['settings'] = array();
        }
        $this->data['filters'][$filter]['settings'][$setting] = $value;
    }

    function asJSON()
    {
        $json = json_encode($this->data);
        // Add spaces so that the field can be folded
        $json = preg_replace('/(["\]}])([,:])(["\[{])/', '$1$2 $3', $json);
        return $json;
    }

    function as_string()
    {
        $json = $this->asJSON();
        $str  = "X-SMTPAPI: " . wordwrap($json, 76, "\n ");
        return $str;
    }
}
```

**myEmail.class.php**

```
<?php
class sendTestEmail
{

    public static function sendEmail($contents, $mailFrom, $mailTo, $subject, $sgHeaders = null, $attachments = null)
    {

        try {
            /*
             * Load connection for mailer
             */
            $connection = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.sendgrid.net', 465, 'ssl')->setUsername(sfconfig::get('app_sendgrid_username'))->setPassword(sfconfig::get('app_sendgrid_password'));

            // setup connection/content
            $mailer  = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($connection);
            $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()->setSubject($subject)->setTo($mailTo);

            $message->setBody($contents, 'text/html');

            // if contains SMTPAPI header add it
            if (null !== $sgHeaders) {
                $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', $sgHeaders);
            }

            // update the from address line to include an actual name
            if (is_array($mailFrom) and count($mailFrom) == 2) {
                $mailFrom = array(
                    $mailFrom['email'] => $mailFrom['name']
                );
            }

            // add attachments to email
            if ($attachments !== null and is_array($attachments)) {
                foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                    $attach = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($attachment['file'], $attachment['mime'])->setFilename($attachment['filename']);
                    $message->attach($attach);
                }
            }

            // Send
            $message->setFrom($mailFrom);
            $mailer->send($message);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new sfException('Error sending email out - ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The email is getting sent properly, but the unsubscribe option is still showing up at the bottom. Is this an issue with the header object or a problem with encoding for the header? Is the variable is still an object when getting added to the headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how JSON encoding works.  Let's take a look at your `as_string` method:

```
function as_string()
{
    $json = $this->asJSON();
    $str  = "X-SMTPAPI: " . wordwrap($json, 76, "\n ");
    return $str;
}
```

This would output something to the effect of:

```
X-SMTPAPI: { "filters": { "subscriptiontrack": { "settings": { "enable": 0 } } } }
```

*You should note that this isn't valid JSON because it is prefixed with "X-SMTPAPI"*.  Instead, you should be calling `asJSON`, but SwiftMailer doesn't know that.

Try switching the header line to:

```
$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', $sgHeaders->asJSON());
```

---

If that doesn't work, can you give us a dump of:

```
$headers = $message->getHeaders();
echo $headers->toString();
```

And have you thought about using the official PHP library instead? https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

Comment: This got it. I am confused, though, as this goes against the Sendgrid docs I think: http://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/SMTP_API_Header_Examples/php.html

Comment: It doesn't actually, the sample just dumps out a stringified version of what you've built so you can read it.

Comment: got it. I was stringifying it, making it invalid.